# Triple jQuery vertical tab

Tags: jquery, html, css

http://jqueryui.com/tabs/#vertical

I need a jQuery vertical tab UI, which should contain three columns.
Is this possible?

Kindly find a screenshot of what I want to achieve:

[image: Screenshot]

**My Code: [JSFiddle Example](http://jsfiddle.net/nEf3C/)**

```
<div id="tabs">
  <ul>
    <li>
      <a href="#tabs-1">Nunc tincidunt</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tabs-2">Proin dolor</a>
    </li>
    <li>
      <a href="#tabs-3">Aenean lacinia</a>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <div id="tabs-1">
    <h2>Content heading 1</h2>

    <p>Proin elit arcu, rutrum commodo, ...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-2">
    <h2>Content heading 2</h2>

    <p>Morbi tincidunt, dui sit amet facilisis feugiat, ...</p>
  </div>
  <div id="tabs-3">
    <h2>Content heading 3</h2>

    <p>Mauris eleifend est et turpis...</p>
    <p>Duis cursus. Maecenas ligula eros, ...</p>
  </div>
</div>
```

**CSS:**

```
.ui-tabs-vertical {
  width: 55em;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav {
  padding: .2em .1em .2em .2em;
  float: left;
  width: 12em;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li {
  clear: left;
  width: 100%;
  border-bottom-width: 1px !important;
  border-right-width: 0 !important;
  margin: 0 -1px .2em 0;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li a {
  display:block;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-nav li.ui-tabs-active {
  padding-bottom: 0;
  padding-right: .1em;
  border-right-width: 1px;
  border-right-width: 1px;
}
.ui-tabs-vertical .ui-tabs-panel {
  padding: 1em;
  float: right;
  width: 40em;
}
```

**JS:**

```
 $(function () {
     $("#tabs").tabs().addClass("ui-tabs-vertical ui-helper-clearfix");
     $("#tabs li").removeClass("ui-corner-top").addClass("ui-corner-left");
 });
```

Answer (score 2):

Since you are asking if it is possible:
**Yes, it is possible.**

Edit: Your provided jsfiddle is not working, because you are using jQuery-functionality and you are not embedding jquery.

Comment: Why don't you try it yourself? If you have any specific problems, the stackoverflow community will help you.